# Show that a finite graph product of finitely generated groups is finitely generated, and similarly for finitely presented groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show that a finite graph product of finitely generated groups is finitely generated,
and similarly for finitely presented groups.

I think when we have a finitely generated groups,the graph product of it is contained something like a loop(condition on generators),every loop will be a generator for graph product,so it is finitely generated.

I know what I explain maybe sounds crazy but it was my feeling.please help me with your knowledge.thanks a lot.

Comment: If you just write down carefully the definition of the graph product, you will answer your own question. Note only that for two groups to commute it suffices that their generators commute.

Answer (score 0):

The paper

R. Brown, M. Bullejos, T. Porter, , `Crossed complexes, free crossed resolutions and graph products of groups', *Proceedings Workshop Korea 2000*, Heldermann Verlag. 27 (2003) 11-26.

gives a crossed complex approach to this type of question on graph products, and also gives reference to related work. The paper is available [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/KOREA3.PDF).

Comment: thank you very much Professor brown,that was really helpful.